# Grails: How to model testing aplication?

Tags: grails, model

I have a problem modeling a application for testing students. I want one `Question` and one `Answer` domain class. In each 'Question' I want to have fast access to all possible answers for this question and to the one correct answer. How to model that in Grails domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- One question `hasMany` possible answers.
- An answer `belongsTo` a question. (May defer because it is not mentioned)
- Out of all the possible answers, only one `isCorrect` answer.

Follow the above pattern if it suits your requirement, you will get the domain classes designed. If you find any difficulty, I can happily post the domain classes. :)

**Here it is:** (*I saw your other question where you were trying to achieve this*)

```
class Question{
    //All possible answer contains the correct answer as well
    static hasMany = [answers: Answer]
}

class Answer{
    static belongsTo = [question: Question]

    //This determines whether the answer is the correct one for the 
    //related question.
    boolean isCorrect
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the domain classes?

Comment: @szczepan Let me know which part is difficult to understand/implement.

Comment: Thank you. What about adding `static hasOne = [acceptedAnswer: Answer]` to `Question`. Isn't it needed to gain one-to-one bidirection relation on the only one answer correct/marked? I mean if there is only boolean field while querying for the accepted answer I would have to search over all answers to this question? As in example C [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html) Yes I decided to ask more general question.

Comment: @szczepan Yes you have to search for correct answer from the list of answers and I hope that will not b a problem. Also, you have to make sure there is only one correct answer out of all answers to the question. I feel this way is better maintainable than having different associations like (hasMany and hasOne) and making them bidirectional. Trying to keep it simple.